# CSS - Gradient transition on hover does work both ways

Tags: html, css

On hover I want to fade in a gradient. I works fine, but on mouse leave there is no transition back. What is wrong, how can I improve the code?

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4paLf352/11/)

HTML

```
<header class="parent">
Hover here!
    <div class="child"></div>


</header>
```

CSS

```
.child {
  height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
      opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  /* Standard */ }



.parent {
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100; 
      opacity: 1 !important; }


  .parent:hover .child {
    opacity: 1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #ededed 30%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0) 99%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #ededed), color-    stop(30%, #ededed), color-stop(99%, rgba(237, 237, 237, 0)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply move your background out of the `:hover` state, onto the `.child` directly- seeing as you are only animating the `opacity` of `.child` this is all that is required. The reason it isnt working at present is also due to the fact you are only listing a single `background` state, that for hover- when you arent hovering the parent, the background is immediately removed (as no default is present) although the opacity is transitioning- so you see the 'jump'

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4paLf352/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You have added the **bg-gradient** to **child on hovering only**. 
Move the background css property to `child{ /* background property */ }` at **default state(mouse leave)**

It works good here http://jsfiddle.net/nvishnu/4paLf352/16/